# may or maybe + can

Tags: modal-verbs

1. *A vegetarian diet **can** provide enough calories for a child's normal growth*.
2. *A vegetarian diet **may** provide enough calories for a child's normal growth.*

Does sentence 2) mean the following:

2a) *A vegetarian diet **maybe + can** (=may) provide enough calories for a child's normal growth.*

ie Sentence 2) = **maybe** + sentence 1)?

Comment: Logically, both mean the same. However, I would understand (1) as implying 'is well able to provide enough calories' and (2) as being more tentative. (It may provide enough if the meals are well-chosen.)

Comment: So in your opinion, (1) implies what is **generally true**, and (2) does not imply that. Rather (2) suggests a  **conditional** meaning. Am I right?

Comment: No - (1) asserts that it is possible (perhaps contradicting someone who claims it is not). (2) says that it may be possible in the right circumstances.